# XPath performance with merged Nokogiri::XML::NodeSets?

Tags: ruby, xml, performance, nokogiri, node-set

I am getting data from a web service, 100 `<row>` per page. My script joins these pages to a Nokogiri::XML::Nodeset. Searching the nodeset via XPath is extremely slow.

This code replaces the web service call and XML parsing, but the symptom is the same:

```
rows = []
(1..500).to_a.each_slice(100) { |slice|
  rows << Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new { |xml|
    xml.root {
      xml.rows {
        slice.each { |num|
          xml.row {
            xml.NUMBER {
              xml.text num
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }.doc.at('/root/rows')
}

rows = rows.map { |a| a.children }.inject(:+)
```

The resulting NodeSet contains nodes from five documents. This seems to be a problem:

```
rows.map { |r| r.document.object_id }.uniq
  => [21430080, 21732480, 21901100, 38743080, 40472240]
```

**The Problem**: The following code runs in about ten seconds. With a non-merged nodeset this is done within a blink of an eye:

```
(1..500).to_a.sample(100).each do |sample|
  rows.at('//row[./NUMBER="%d"]' % sample)
end
```

Does somebody have a solution to merge the Nodesets a better way or merge the documents?

I would like to keep the behaviour of only one nodeset, as this data is practically one big nodeset, which was split by the web service for technical reasons.

Comment: Why are you trying to assemble a nodeset? Why not just collect the data you need?

Comment: The data collection and assembly part is done by a webservice interface class (the builder is to demonstrate the behaviour). This method returns a NodeSet. The xpath-code runs by the code which are using this class. It would be nice if I dont have to change the interface of the class methods.

Comment: Nokogiri is very fast, and is built upon an industry-standard XML parser. You haven't give us an example of the XML you are parsing or the NodeSets you are appending together, and, to me, trying to compare the speed of parsing vs. building isn't really valid -- you're comparing apples to oranges. As is, your question doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: The question is not about the building, that is just the example nodeset generation. It is about the xpath query. I added a mark to clarify. It seems that the example is core dumping in some environments. Iam currently trying to isolate the problem code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to merge the Nodesets is to detach the nodes with Node#remove and add them to the other nodeset:

```
nodeset = nil
rows.each do |slice|
  if nodeset.nil?
    nodeset = slice
  else
    slice.children.each do |row|
      nodeset.add_child(row.remove)
    end
  end
end
```